# it is not displaying the messages correctly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a javscript function below which displays a message depending on on the result:

```
   function stopImageUpload(success){
          var result = '';
          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
          }  
          return true;   
    }
```

The code below always displays the message "The file was uploaded successfully!"

```
   <?php

       $destination_path = str_replace("//", "/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/")."ImageFiles";

       $result = 0;

       $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);

       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
          $result = 1;
       }

       sleep(1);

    ?>

   <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
      window.top.window.stopImageUpload(1);
   </script>
```

But if I change the last line to this below then it always displays the message "There was an error during file upload!". Why is this and how  can it be fixed so it displays the right message depending on the result?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: What value are you getting from <?php echo $result; ?>

Comment: The value of result is 0, but why is it always 0 is what I don't get. If there is something wrong when moving a file then what I can I look at to see if file is moving or not?

Answer (score 1):

Find out what this `<?php echo $result; ?>` actually renders to. Just look in the page source.

Most likely, it will be `0`. Then try to find out why `move_uploaded_file` returns false. Probably, there's something wrong happening while moving the file.